# Change Font color onclick Radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

We are displaying text & two radio buttons in page....

Once we click on Radio buttons, we are changing background color of page according to radio button....

**Requirement** :

Instead of Background color, i want to change the **text color** onclick radio button....

I tried below , but it did't worked :

```
.orange input:checked ~ .text {
  color: #F4511E;
}
```

**Code Snippet**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.button span:hover {
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange .button span {
  background: #FF5722;
}

.amber .button span {
  background: #FFC107;
}


.layer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  /*transition: ease .3s;*/
  z-index: -1;
}

.orange input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: #F4511E;
}

.amber input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: #FFB300;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
<div class="text">text</div>
 
<label class="orange">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>

<label class="amber">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="amber">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>


</body>
```

Comment: you have to use jquery to change color text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JS/jQuery for this because `> + ~` this are siblings selector so it only select item that are next to it

```
+ is the immediate subsequent sibling selector
~ is the any subsequent sibling selector
```

UPDATED [PEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgXpje)

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function() {
    let color = $(this).parent().find('div.button span').css('background-color');
    $('.text').css('color', color);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.button span:hover {
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange .button span {
  background: #FF5722;
}

.amber .button span {
  background: #FFC107;
}


.layer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  /*transition: ease .3s;*/
  z-index: -1;
}

/* .orange input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: #F4511E;
}

.amber input:checked ~ .layer {
  background: #FFB300;
} */
```

```html
<body>
 
<div class="text">text</div>
 
<label class="orange">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>

<label class="amber">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="amber">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>


</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i glad to help you bro

Comment: Hi, I updated your code in my project, but its not working there, when you get free time, please check [codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/gyvWgR) & click on text.....

Comment: this code is not working because you pass text from js, let me solve that

Comment: bro your code is something wrong you are messing with code, so i cant click on button and get value from that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191981/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-nisharg-shah).

Answer (score 1):

Use below jQuery using `siblings`

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
  if($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() == 'amber'){
    $(this).parent().siblings('div.text').css('color', '#FFB300');
  }
  else{
    $(this).parent().siblings('div.text').css('color', '#F4511E');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.button span:hover {
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange .button span {
  background: #FF5722;
}

.amber .button span {
  background: #FFC107;
}


.layer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  /*transition: ease .3s;*/
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 
<div class="text">text</div>
 
<label class="orange">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="orange">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>

<label class="amber">
  <input type="radio" name="color" value="amber">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>


</body>
```

Comment: that is not perfect answer because if there is color more than two, conditions complex the code !

Comment: @NishargShah Yes it is complex for more color using if else...but not sure about which is perfect...

Comment: look my answer, first of all i got parent of element after find element and select background color of it and applied to text

Comment: @NishargShah Yes nice way

Comment: thanks bro, i appreciate your answer but condition make them complex, +1 for appreciation

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery/js for that - This is a Solution with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = $('.text')
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var color = $(this).val();
            text.css('color', color);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tpq16r5L/4/

Alos please be aware that amber is no usable color, so I changed that for exemplary usage to green

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer is here

```js
function myColour(clr)
{
alert(clr);
if(clr == 'orange')
   document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].style.color = '#F4511E'
  else if(clr == 'amber')
      document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].style.color = '#FFB300'
     else
       document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].style.color = 'black'
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 180px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  transition: ease .3s;
}

.button span:hover {
  padding: 10px;
}

.orange .button span {
  background: #FF5722;
}

.amber .button span {
  background: #FFC107;
}


.layer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  /*transition: ease .3s;*/
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
<div class="text">text</div>
 
<label class="orange">
  <input onclick="myColour('orange')" type="radio" name="color" value="orange">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>

<label class="amber">
  <input onclick="myColour('amber')" type="radio" name="color" value="amber">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <div class="button"><span></span></div>
</label>


</body>
```

Comment: that is not perfect answer because if there is color more than two, conditions complex the code !